# mvvm-light: Normal Property or DependencyProperty

Tags: mvvm-light

In mvvm-light, it comes with two property-creation snippets:  mvvminpc to create a 'normal' property; and mvvmpropa to create an attached property (aka dependency property).  I just want to know if there is any guidance on what to take into consideration when choosing which one to use?

Answer (score 3):

I've been also searching for a while on these property topics for MVVM light. Below is my understanding of the property snippets provided in MVVM light. There aren't really any cases where you would use one over the other because they are for different purposes.

**Bindable Property** - Bindable properties are created in your ViewModels to expose data which your view will display.

Examples include: Displaying a collection of Employees, or the selected employee information.

**Dependency Property** - View specific when it comes to the code snippet. These properties can be set to a constant value or use data binding for changes *depending* on the viewmodel data.

Examples include: A textblock control's "Text" property is a dependency property. The "Height" and "Width" properties are also dependency properties.

**Attach Property** - Also used more specifically for user controls. This property is added to a parent control. Child controls use these properties to behave a certain way within the parent control.

Example includes: a Dockpanel has a "Dock" (Attached Property Name) that isn't used by the Dockpanel itself. It is used by the children contained inside of it, the children will now be able to set the property: DockPanel.Dock="Top".

```
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeName}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <Button Content="Click Here" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    </DockPanel>
```

In the example code above:

The **Bindable Property** is the EmployeeName, which would be a public property in the viewmodel code.

The **Dependency Property** is the Text="" property of the textblock and the Content="" property of the button.

The **Attach Property** is the DockPanel.Dock property used in the Textblock and button, but is actually exposed by the Dockpanel itself. Notice that the Dockpanel doesn't contain any of the .Dock code, only the children do.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency properties are recommended when you create UI components (controls, etc.): they have better time performances for binding.

Normal properties are used if you have business object or if you dont have/create UI controls.